# Metropolitan Railway Datasets

Tags: data-request, transportation, public-transport

**Where can I find commuter-related datasets for underground transportation (subway, metro)?**

The *[NY MTA](http://mta.info/developers/download.html)* is a good example, and there is also the [*Transport for London* data feeds](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/businessandpartners/syndication/). I would like to have from other cities around the world.

I'm looking for the following:

- Commuter entrance & exit stations
- Times & durations of travel
- Passenger routes

Comment: I take it you're not talking about the fast-food restaurant, Subway.

Comment: Mexico City metro site has yearly data about payed/free accesses, stations with more/less users, amount of users for each station and line and other general operations data.
http://www.metro.df.gob.mx/operacion/cifrasoperacion.html#7

Answer (score 1):

The authoritative source for Chicago transit data is http://www.transitchicago.com/data/.

[Steven Vance](http://stevevance.net/) did quite a bit of preparation and organization around Chicago transit data and [posted it on his blog in 2010](http://www.stevencanplan.com/download-transit-gis-data/). I don't see any note that indicates the data has been updated since then, but it's still probably useful as an overview to what data there is and what you might need to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Find DC Metro datasets here:
https://www.wmata.com/rider_tools/developer_resources.cfm

Hopefully, downloads will be faster than their trains.

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't intend it as such, but there are a few of us that are still sensitive to the [reason that the WMATA trains have been running slow](http://dcist.com/2009/07/wmata_trains_will_operate_in_manual.php) -- the Wherleys were family friends.